# Expression to be reduced by using Boolean algebra

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

Hi I have this expression **XY'Z+YY'+X+XY'+XZ** ( ' means not) Can anyone please show me the simplification of this expression? Thanks in advance.

This is what i got so far:

```
XY'Z+YY'+XY'+X(1+Z)
XY'Z+YY'+XY'+XY'+X
Y'(XZ+Y)+X(1+Y')  
Y'(XZ+Y)+X
```

I know 1+Y=1 but 1+Y'=1 too?

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you're stuck. Don't just copy and paste a question from your homework.

Comment: I fixed, i though it wasn't relevant to post what i tried, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Y'(XZ+Y)+X
```

change this back to:

```
XY'Z+YY'+X
```

Then simplify a bit:

```
XY'Z+YY'+X
YY' + X(1+Y'Z)
0 + X
X
```